# Flex: Highlighting element on mouse over

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have a canvas with several small canvases on it.

Like this:

```
public class Board extends Canvas
{
    public function Board()
    {
        //cellWidth = this.width/boardSize;
        //this.drawMech();
        addEventListener(FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE, creationComplete);
        super();
    }
```

then I added balls to the board using this.addChild(ball);

And ball

```
public class Ball extends Canvas
{       
    public function Ball()
    {
        addEventListener(FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE, creationComplete);
        super();
    }

    public function creationComplete(event:Event):void
    {
        trace("created stones");
        //Alert.show("Creation complete ever called");
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, mouseOver);
        //addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, mouseOut);
    }
```

What I want to implement is:

I want the ball which I added to canvas Board, became highlighted (e.g. changed it's color) on mouse over on it, and became unhighlighted after mouse is go out of ball.

What I have done to achieve it.
I added 2 event listeners to ball class, in order to listen for mouse over and mouse out events...But for some reason they was not called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class's name is `Ball` and constructor's name is `Stone`. The line `addEventListener(FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE, creationComplete);` will never be called. Change the constructor name to Ball.

Comment: Fixed. Sorry it was my mistake. Have problem. Seems that item became highlighted only when mouse is on it's edges.